# Reliable weekend forex source that can act as credible data for Monday APAC morning forex trade

Tags: fx, futures, forward, spot-rate

In general most of the forex market closes by 10:00 pm london time on Friday and opens back on Monday morning APAC time , somewhere around Sunday evening London time. I am interested in knowing if there are some reliable forex spot ( may be even forwards or future ) trade happening on Saturday or during first half of Sunday.

If so what are those and how can i have look at those data ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends on what pairs you want data for. But in general, no. Even if you can see intraday data in those 'dead' times, the quotes can be very stale (hours old).

Comment: In general, the FX market is 24 hours by 5.5 days. What is the meaning of a quote (exchnage rate or ir swap) if you cannot execute until Monday morning? Maybe one day the markets will be 24/7, but they're not, as of this writing.

Comment: FX markets are always 24 x 7 and always will be. Reason is, I can always trade with you anytime we agree. Other parts of the system (quote platforms, banks etc) may not be open 24 x 7 and that does have an impact. The point is, there are some times where there is not many buyers and sellers willing to agree terms. It totally depends on the FX pair. For example AUDJPY might start quite early in the week, or in the middle east where the sabbath falls on days other than Sundays.

Comment: Some people I know used to have a small interest rates swaps desk in the Middle East whose main purpose was to allow trading IR swaps on Saturdays and Sundays. (That closed for other reasons.) I'm not actually aware of anyone doing this now. But the point it - it was a very different market, with a very different bid-ask spread and all behavior. You wouldn't want to mix their quotes with Mon-Fri quotes.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, the conventional answer is 'no'.

However, here is one interesting angle of the new cryptocurrency trading market to me - it operates 24/7/365 (yes even Christmas day!). Now I'm told that the biggest markets are the US and Korea, so perhaps, given sufficient liquidity, we could back out a USDKRW rate over the weekend given the USD and KRW spot rates for a given digital asset?

The futures markets are more liquid than the cash, but as the margin requirements need to be posted in spot, that should guarantee some transaction quantity round-the-clock.

[image: Binance futures exchange]

Here is the futures exchange at binance.com ticking away very happily on Saturday morning

And here is a python snippet (provided caveat emptor!) that will pull the most recent BTC-USD and BTC-EUR trades from coinbase, and calculate the approximate rate for EURUSD any time - weekend not a problem! You will need to `pip install cbpro` first:

```
import cbpro

public_client = cbpro.PublicClient()

for x in public_client.get_product_trades(product_id='BTC-USD'):
    last_USD = x
    print("Dollar last trade time: {}".format(last_USD['time']))
    break

for x in public_client.get_product_trades(product_id='BTC-EUR'):
    last_EUR = x
    print("Euro last trade time: {}".format(last_EUR['time']))
    break

float(last_USD['price']) / float(last_EUR['price'])
```

Which gives:

[image: EURUSD from weekend BTC transactions]